# Why is Windows 10 Enterprise virtualizing my .NET Framework 4.8 application?

Tags: c#, .net

I accidentally retargeted a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application to .NET Framework 4.8 (by opening it in Visual Studio 2022)..

And now the application will only write its data file to the VirtualStore directory of the logged-in user, whereas before it wrote the file to a subdirectory of C:/ProgramData. This breaks the functionality of the application, since no matter what permissions I open up on C:\ProgramData, it doesn't fix the issue.

Do I need to retarget back to 4.7.2 to make Windows stop virtualizing the application?

Or, is there something I need to install to fix this?

TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows only redirects writes in protected folders like C:\ProgramData into the per-user VirtualStore folder for **some** 32-bit x86
applications; this feature is called [UAC file system virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works#virtualization). Try checking the old and new versions of your app in Task Manager to see if the old version ran as 64-bit x64 while the new version runs as 32-bit.

If you do see that the old version ran as 64-bit while the new version runs as 32-bit, then it's possible that when Visual Studio upgraded your app's solution as part of retargeting from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 4.8, it turned on the ["Prefer 32-bit" build switch](https://web.archive.org/web/20131121072002/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/) on the .EXE assembly's project. That switch makes Windows run the program as 32-bit even if the .EXE is also marked as "Any CPU".

If "Prefer 32-bit" is turned on for the .EXE project, turn it off and rebuild the .EXE. After that, the app should hopefully run as 64-bit and not write into VirtualStore anymore.

Comment: Thank you soo much, I will try this. I couldn't find information anywhere about this and you've been very helpful and fast!